# When a radio button is checked in one asp page,the result has to be displayed in another asp page..How to do that..pls explain?

Tags: asp.net

Radio button in one aspx page  ,
should display result in another aspx page

where was 2012 olympics held??

```
    <form name="form1" action="resultpage.aspx" onclick="submit">
        <input type="radio" name="VanPersie" id="a" value="paris" />paris<br />
        <input type="radio" name="VanPersie" id="b" value="london" />london<br />
        <input type="radio" name="VanPersie" id="c" value="rome" />rome<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>.
```

Above  code displays my first home page and it has to be redirected to another aspx page....so when..london is checked by the user,it has to display  the  correct answer and i.e. London ..how to design the result page...

Comment: add some code and explain question by editing

Answer (score 0):

1 You can use this code

```
var result = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
Response.Redirect("AnotherPage?id=" + result);
```

In page you can get with

```
`QueryString["id"]`;
```

2 You can also use

```
yourButton.PostBackUrl = "AnotherPage.aspx?qid=" + radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a **button** that fire a event in your page, you can set the **PostbackUrl** attribute to the page you want and where you can retrive the value

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Send to other page" postbackurl="yourPage.aspx" />
```

[Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The answer has to be london...so how to get it from the above radio value..by name or by id in asp...

Answer (score 0):

First set the **method** attribute to the form to **POST**

```
<form name="form1" action="resultpage.aspx" onclick="submit" method="POST">
```

Then, if you subit this form from an **ASP** page, in the **resultpage.aspx** you can get the radio value by:

```
//C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Request.Form["VanPersie"];
}

'VB
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Request.Form("VanPersie")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks....The answer has to be london...so how to get it from the above radio value..by name or by id in asp

Comment: by the **name** in the destination page

Comment: Of course, when you submit the form, the sended data is identifyed by the name. If you have different name, you must refer each name and check each value. In your code you have a group of radio because they have the same name. It's right In the **destination page** use the **field name** for get the value.